# What is the name of the skin part between nose and lip in portuguese?

Tags: uso-de-palavras

I'd like to know what is the name of the part of body between the nose and lip in portuguese.

[image: skin between nose and lip]

I guess that exists some scientific term that I can find in google, but I'm looking for the popular name.

[Here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166884/what-is-the-name-of-the-area-of-skin-between-the-nose-and-the-upper-lip-mouth) is a similar question in English SE where i get the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [translation](https://translate.google.com/#en/pt/philtrum) of *philtrum*, the English word for the area between the nose and upper lip, I discovered it is called *Filtro Labial* in Portuguese.

A quick search about this term showed a few results like this one in [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filtro_labial) or [this one](http://m.megacurioso.com.br/corpo-humano/42923-10-partes-da-anatomia-humana-com-nomes-pra-la-de-bizarros.htm) (about *bizarre* names for human body parts), but those 2 links are not authoritative resources on anatomy I'm not an expert, so I'm not sure where to look for an official name.

Answer (score 3):

One could use "buço", by extension.

> Definition: the hair above the upper lip in men and some women.

[Source](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/bu%C3%A7o)

Comment: "Buço" is mostly used to name the women's moustache.

Comment: In any case, it's the closest to a reference to this particular area of the body, wouldn't you agree? One could say "a região do buço" and it would solve the problem in question.

Answer (score 3):

## Lábio Superior (picture 1)

Source: [Lábio - Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A1bio#Histologia)

## Filtro Labial (picture 2)

Source: [Filtro Labial - Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filtro_labial)

Comment: O que achei sobre isso [site](http://www.malthus.com.br/mg_total.asp?id=98)